# Highlight the answer option in quiz after option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In this quiz code, I want to highlight the answer option after any right or wrong option is selected. I want the right option must get green background color and be shown for some time before moving to the next question.

```js
var images = {
"One":"https://i.imgur.com/w4uroFC.jpg",
"Two":"https://i.imgur.com/X53yYlN.jpg",
"Two":"https://i.imgur.com/X53yYlN.jpg",
"Three":"https://i.imgur.com/l5IFfk1.jpg",
"Four":"https://i.imgur.com/tOXEexG.jpg",
}  
function populate() {
if (quiz.isEnded()) {
showScores();
} else {
// show question
var element = document.getElementById("question");
element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

// show options
var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
element.innerHTML = images[choices[i]]? '<img src="'+images[choices[i]]+'"/>':choices[i];
guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
}

showProgress();
}
};

function guess(id, guess) {
var button = document.getElementById(id);
button.onclick = function() {
quiz.guess(guess);
populate();
}
};

function showProgress() {
var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
var element = document.getElementById("progress");
element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> You scored: " + quiz.score + "/2</h2>";
var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

var questions = [
  
 new Question("Choose One From Below!", ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], "One"),

   new Question("Choose Two From Below!", ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], "Two"),
];

function Question(text, choices, answer) {
this.text = text;
this.choices = choices;
this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
return this.answer === choice;
}


function Quiz(questions) {
this.score = 0;
this.questions = questions;
this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
  
this.score++;
}

this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```css
body {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.grid {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.buttons img
{
width:200px;
}
.grid h1 {
font-family: "Montserrat";
background-color: red;
font-size: 35px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 2px 0px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
hr
{
margin-top: 50px;
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
}
#score {
color: red;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
font-family: "monospace";
font-size: 30px;
color: red;
}

.buttons {
margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0,
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3 {

    padding: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
    border: none;
margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;

}

#btn0:hover,
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover,
#btn3:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #ffc107;
}

#btn0:focus,
#btn1:focus,
#btn2:focus,
#btn3:focus {
outline: 0;
}

#progress {
color: #2b2b2b;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Random Quiz</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.grid {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.buttons img
{
width:200px;
}
.grid h1 {
font-family: "Montserrat";
background-color: red;
font-size: 35px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 2px 0px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
hr
{
margin-top: 50px;
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
}
#score {
color: red;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
font-family: "monospace";
font-size: 30px;
color: red;
}

.buttons {
margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0,
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3 {

    padding: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
    border: none;
margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;

}

#btn0:hover,
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover,
#btn3:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #ffc107;
}

#btn0:focus,
#btn1:focus,
#btn2:focus,
#btn3:focus {
outline: 0;
}

#progress {
color: #2b2b2b;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
<div id="quiz">
<h1>Random Quiz</h1>
<hr style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />
<p id="question"></p>
<div class="buttons">
<button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
<button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>

<button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
<button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
</div>
<hr style="margin-top: 50px;" />
<footer>
<p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
</footer>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what did you try? what's not working? what the code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by using `setTimeout` to delay the execution of `populate` after a guess.

During that delay, you would change the background color to reflect what answer was correct:

```js
var images = {
  "One": "https://i.imgur.com/w4uroFC.jpg",
  "Two": "https://i.imgur.com/X53yYlN.jpg",
  "Two": "https://i.imgur.com/X53yYlN.jpg",
  "Three": "https://i.imgur.com/l5IFfk1.jpg",
  "Four": "https://i.imgur.com/tOXEexG.jpg",
}

let buttonChoices = {
  "One": "btn0",
  "Two": "btn1",
  "Three": "btn2",
  "Four": "btn3"
}

function populate() {
  if (quiz.isEnded()) {
    showScores();
  } else {
    // show question
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

    // show options
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
      element.innerHTML = images[choices[i]] ? '<img src="' + images[choices[i]] + '"/>' : choices[i];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }

    showProgress();
  }
};

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.onclick = function() {
    quiz.guess(guess);
    setTimeout(() => {
      populate();
      button.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }, 2000);
  }
};

function showProgress() {
  var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("progress");
  element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
  var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
  gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> You scored: " + quiz.score + "/2</h2>";
  var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
  element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

var questions = [

  new Question("Choose One From Below!", ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], "One"),

  new Question("Choose Two From Below!", ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], "Two"),
];

function Question(text, choices, answer) {
  this.text = text;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
  return this.answer === choice;
}


function Quiz(questions) {
  this.score = 0;
  this.questions = questions;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
  let selectedButton = document.getElementById(buttonChoices[this.getQuestionIndex().answer]);
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {

    this.score++;
    selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  } else {
    selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "Red"
  }

  this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
  return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.grid {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.buttons img {
  width: 200px;
}

.grid h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
}

#score {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
  font-family: "monospace";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0,
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3 {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
}

#btn0:hover,
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover,
#btn3:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffc107;
}

#btn0:focus,
#btn1:focus,
#btn2:focus,
#btn3:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#progress {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head lang="en">

  <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
  <title>Random Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div id="quiz">
      <h1>Random Quiz</h1>
      <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />
      <p id="question"></p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
        <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>

        <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
        <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin-top: 50px;" />
      <footer>
        <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

There are a couple of things I modified for the sake of the example that are sort of hacky I think, mostly due to my infamiliarity with your code. Make sure to do the necessary modifications if this doesn't satisfy your specific use-case but the most important parts are these:

In `Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer)` function:

```
  let selectedButton = document.getElementById(buttonChoices[this.getQuestionIndex().answer]);
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {

    this.score++;
    selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  } else {
    selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "Red"
  }
```

This will modify the background color to reflect green for correct and red for wrong

In `guess()` function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    populate();
    button.style.backgroundColor = "";
}, 2000);
```

This delays the execution of `populate()` by 2 seconds so it doesn't switch instantly.

Kindly note that I also added this:

```
let buttonChoices = {
  "One": "btn0",
  "Two": "btn1",
  "Three": "btn2",
  "Four": "btn3"
}
```

because I wasn't exactly sure what the best way to get the selected btn id would be. Since you probably do, you should modify it / get rid of it.